# "do it themselves" or "do it by themselves"

Tags: prepositions, reflexive-pronouns, emphasis

> ‘Marvellous idea!’ Peter said. ‘They will do it **themselves**!’

Could I use "by themselves" here?

> ‘Marvellous idea!’ Peter said. ‘They will do it **by themselves**!’